# Somar valores de uma TD com javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Boa tarde, tenho um script que me ajudaram a fazer por aqui mesmo, que cria uma tabela após ler informações de uma textarea.
Depois que a tabela esta pronta eu queria somar os valores de uma das coluna da tabela.
Eu até consigo calcular o total quando os dados são inseridos pela primeira vez, porem se eu adicionar uma linha ou excluir uma linha eu nao consigo atualizar esse valor, então pensei em criar uma função para recalcular esse valor e chamar ela sempre que fizer uma alteração na tabela.
Criei a função só que ela nao funciona bem, fica repetindo VARIAS vezes o mesmo campo e na segunda linha por exemplo ela não retorna os dados só a palavra **undefined**

Segue o código que gera a tabela.

```
function addItens () 
{
   let total =0;
   // Elemento textarea:
   const texto = $("#texto");

    // Elemento table:
    const table = $("#products-table");

    // Divide o conteúdo de textarea em linhas:
    let linhas = texto.val().split("\n");

    // Percorre todas as linhas:
    for (i in linhas)
    {
      // Verifica se a linha não está vazia:
      if (linhas[i])
      {
        // Divide o conteúdo da linha em colunas:
        let retorno = linhas[i].split(" ");

        // Cria uma nova linha na tabela:
        let newRow = $("<tr>");

      // Percorre todas as colunas:
      for (j in retorno)
      {
        // Verifica se a coluna não está vazia:
      if (retorno[j])
      {
        // Cria a nova coluna na tabela:
        let newCol = $("<td>");
        // Adiciona o conteúdo na coluna:
        newCol.html(retorno[j]);

        // Adiciona a coluna na linha:
        newRow.append(newCol);
    }
  }

  total += parseInt(retorno[2]);
 // alert(total);

  // Cria a coluna de ação:
  let action = $("<td>");

  // Adiciona a classe "actions":
  action.addClass("actions");

  // Adiciona o botão Remover à coluna de ação:
  action.html('<button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button>');

  // Adiciona a coluna na linha:
  newRow.append(action);

  // Adiciona a linha na tabela:
    table.append(newRow);
   }
 }
```

aqui e a função que eu criei para percorrer a tabela e pegar o valor da coluna que eu preciso

```
function calculaTotal(){

var table = $("#products-table");
var linhas = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var colunas = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (i in linhas){
for(j in colunas){
    alert(colunas[i].innerText);
  };
 }
```

Comment: Qual das colunas você quer somar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa sua tentativa de misturar jQuery com JavaScript *vanilla* apenas para selecionar elementos do DOM ficou bem estranha. Funciona, mas não há porque fazê-lo, deixa o código inconsistente. Se estás a utilizar jQuery, aproveite as funcionalidades do mesmo, já que você quer manipular o DOM e é exatamente para isso que ele foi criado.

Com o seletor `#products-table tr td:nth-child(1)` você estará selecionando todas as primeiras colunas de cada linha. Para somá-las, basta iterar sobre as mesmas e acumular seu valor em uma variável, retornando esta variável ao final. Para deixar mais genérico, você pode passar por parâmetro a coluna desejada.

Veja o exemplo:

```js
function getTotal(column = 1) {
  let result = 0;
  let columns = $("#products-table tr td:nth-child(" + column + ")");

  columns.each(i => {
    result += parseInt($(columns[i]).html());
  });

  return result;
}

console.log("Soma da primeira coluna: " + getTotal(1));
console.log("Soma da terceira coluna: " + getTotal(3));
console.log("Soma da quarta coluna: " + getTotal(4));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="products-table" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>produto1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="actions"><button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>prodto2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td class="actions"><button class="btn btn-large btn-danger" onclick="RemoveTableRow(this)" type="button">Remover</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Assim poderá chamar a função `getTotal` sempre que necessário.

Comment: Essa estória de "misturar jQuery com javascript" sempre me soa estranha; jQuery _é_ javascript, usando alguns objetos definidos numa biblioteca. Melhor seria dizer "misturar jQuery com manipulação direta do DOM" (_Document Object Model_, a API que os navegadores expõem para se manipular uma página via script).

Comment: @Wtrmute de fato, seria mais exato dizer isso, mas a ideia que quis passar ficou clara. O fato de usar `$("#x")` em uma linha e `getElementByTagName("tr")` em outra deixa o código bastante inconsistente e deve ser evitado fazer. De qualquer forma, editarei a resposta para fazer a alteração.

Comment: Não discordo que seja necessário evitar (embora lá por 2007 houvesse quem recomendasse usar `document.getElementById('foo')` em vez de `$('#foo')` por questões de eficiência), mas temos que evitar propagar o equívoco de que jQuery não é javascript. Você sabe que é, eu sei que é, mas nem todo garoto de 17 anos começando a programar que lerá esta pergunta daqui a 3 anos saberá, e pode acabar aprendendo algo errado.

Answer (score 0):

**Tente esta:**

```
function calculaTotal(){    
      var colunas = document.querySelectorAll('#products-table tr td');
      var numColunas = colunas.length;
      for (let i=0; i<numColunas; i++){
         alert(colunas[i].textContent);    
      }
}
```